# Running C# task freezes WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I want to build a Poker application with C#/WPF.
The CPU players take their turn, but when its time for the user to act i have a problem, because I want to wait for the input of the player, but my loop freezes the UI.
The code goes like this:

```
public override async void TakeTurn()
{
        await WaitForUserInput();
}

private async Task<int> WaitForUserInput()
{
    await Task.Run((() => WaitForUserInput2()));
    return 42;
}

private void WaitForUserInput2()
{
    while (BetsFinished == false || Game.PlayersRound.Contains(this))
    {
        //Loop that gets broken by user interaction
    }
}
```

The task that I run would get broken by user input (Button click would set BetsFinished to true), which isnt possible because the UI is frozen as soon as TakeTurn gets called. The code is in a Model class, so it has no direct connection to View if that matters. User interaction would happen over a button that is bound to a command.

The TakeTurn() method gets called from my Poker class, that defines the flow of the game.

I tried multiple setups (for example no await in front of WaitForUserInput();) but without success.

So my goal is to let this loop run without freezing the UI.

Comment: Why is there a loop waiting for user input anyway. This is bound to cause problems

Comment: `while (BetsFinished == false || Game.PlayersRound.Contains(this))` eats up all your CPU.

Comment: @ColinM As im not really expecting a value there, is it still better to just return some value like the 42 in WaitForUserInput()?

Comment: An async method without return value should be `async Task Method()`. When it doesn't do anything but calling Task.Run, it doesn't need to be async: `private Task Method() { return Task.Run(() => OtherMethod()); }`. Then `await Method();`

Comment: I feel like you're asking the wrong question here. Generally speaking a loop waiting for user feedback in a UI application is a poor design. A better question might be "How do I wait for user feedback before continuing processing in my WPF app"?

Answer (score 3):

A UI application is very different than a Console application. In a UI application, you should structure your logic to *react* to user input, whatever that input is. In other words, you should *not* have a `WaitForUserInput` method; the presence of that method indicates your program is trying to drive the user, instead of the user driving the program.

Instead, you should keep your game state in memory, and when the user clicks a `Bid` button (or whatever), then *react* to that user input by moving to the new state. It's fine to constrain user choice - e.g., if you want to disable user buttons while the computer players are making their move. But (mis)using `async` and `await` to encode the expected interaction logic is asking for a world of pain.

P.S. For a WPF poker game, I don't see any I/O necessary, and therefore there probably won't be any `async` or `await` at all in your final app.